# How to fix extra zeroes being returned

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I'm trying to copy an array into a new, then return that new array. The problem is that I need to only copy the array from a certain range.

I made a for statement that assigns an int i to the parameter that decides the start, and set it to run until it reaches the parameter that decides the end.

```
int[] newSound = new int[sound.length];

for (int i = start_index; i < end_index; ++i) {
    newSound[i] = sound[i];
}
return newSound;
```

If the array was [3, 2, 5, 6, 9] and the range was [1, 3], it would only return [2, 5, 6]. The problem is that when I run my program, it returns [0, 2, 5, 6, 0]. Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Comment: Why not use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-)?

Comment: If you want a smaller array, you need to not make it the same size as the original.

Comment: If you already have the destination array, you can also use `System.arrayCopy()`

Comment: Do you intend for your `end_index` to be included in the final array? The code you posted will not do this, which is what I based my answer on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fix by creating your array to just the size of the copy range (`start_index` to `end_index`):

```
int[] newSound = new int[end_index - start_index];
```

Your loop should now be:

```
for (int i = start_index; i < end_index; ++i) {
    newSound[i - start_index] = sound[i];
}
```

---

As suggested in the comments, [**`Arrays.copyOfRange`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-) is a better alternative to the above because it takes care of out-of-bound index and negative ranges.

Use it like this:

```
int[] newSound = Arrays.copyOfRange(sound, start_index, end_index);
```

Comment: Thank you so much this fixed the problem. However, I'm still confused as to why the for loop needs to be newSound[i - start_index] instead of just newSound[I].

Comment: @Spiriteater because `i` may not start at zero. So subtract `start_index` from each `i` to guarantee that we start at zero and then `1`, `2`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Your destination array is of length 5 and you're copying into the same positions as the source.

You want to do this, I believe:

```
int[] newSound = new int[end_index - start_index + 1];
for (int i = start_index; i <= end_index; ++i) {
  newSound[i - start_index] = sound[i];
}
return newSound;
```